# Regular expression to validate url with sub folder

Tags: regex

I have a regular expression like below in place to validate urls.

```
/http(s)?:\/\/([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]+(\/)?$/
```

The expression successfully validate below urls.

1. http://www.google.com
2. http://google.com
3. https://www.google.com
4. https://google.com

Now i have a requirement to allow sub directory in urls which can allow n-level of sub directory. Like

http://www.google.com/dir1/dir2/...

**How can i allow sub directory in above regular expression?**

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
http(s)?:\/\/([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]+(\/)?[.a-z0-9/-]+
```

Also you can check this [related thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/161738/what-is-the-best-regular-expression-to-check-if-a-string-is-a-valid-url) in which Matthew O'Riordan gives the regex to validate a url:

```
/((([A-Za-z]{3,9}:(?:\/\/)?)(?:[-;:&=\+\$,\w]+@)?[A-Za-z0-9.-]+|(?:www.|[-;:&=\+\$,\w]+@)[A-Za-z0-9.-]+)((?:\/[\+~%\/.\w-_]*)?\??(?:[-\+=&;%@.\w_]*)#?(?:[\w]*))?)/
```